# How can I run a function when vc-diff finishes?

Tags: hooks, diff, vc

The diff command can be async, of course. Is there an easy way to run a function when the async or sync diff command finished running and the diff buffer's contents is ready?

I checked, but I saw no hook for this.

Answer (score 2):

A quick look seems to indicate that the only way you can do it is by [advising](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) `vc-diff-finish`: it seems to be called after an async diff is done, so you should be able to piggyback whatever you want to do on it.

Untested.